# how does chrome dev-tool keep the breakpoints when debugging js file with timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

eg `index.js?t=12345678`

The break points disappered after refreshing.

It is inconvenient to add break points every time.

```
<script>
    document.writeln("<script src=\"assets/js/index.js?t="+(new Date()).getTime()+"\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"><\/script>");
</script>
```

Of course, I can modify my source code, delete getTime() or add debugger. But I want to know is there a way for me to debug without changing others' source code.

Comment: Use sourcemaps.